# Don't show a field when a more important field is shown in a View Drupal 7

Tags: 7, views, entities

On my homepage blog messages from the users are shown. When a user adds a Youtube movie and/or one or more pictures these are shown as a preview.
The thing is though that when a user picks a movie and one or more pictures the home page message show the Youtube movie and the picture. But when both are added to a blog message I only want to see the youtube preview, so Youtube is more important than the picture so the picture should not be shown.
When there are only pictures 1 picture is shown (this works fine).
How can I change something in my View to make it prioritize Youtube over the picture so it doesn't the picture when there is a Youtube movie.

Screenie of what I have now, so the picture has to leave:
http://imageshack.com/a/img844/1833/bqer.jpg

I have a multisite setup with 11 websites so the easiest solution is welcome :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Views Conditional](https://drupal.org/project/views_conditional) module. It does exactly what you want to achieve.

> How to use Views Conditional in your Views:
>
> 1. Create a view. Add some fields under "FIELDS".
> 2. Click on "ADD" next to fields. Scroll down to "Views: Views
>      Conditional", probably found near the bottom of the list.
> 3. Add and configure fields...
> 4. Choose a field to run a condition against, and provide values
>      accordingly.
> 5. Save, views conditional handles the logic and returns as specified.

Comment: You might need to hide the fields from display and then use them after the condition probably.

Comment: Looks like the answer I need!
Thanks!
Will come back here if I have problems but I think it's ok :D